# Black Terminal - can't write anything on it

Tags: command-line

I was trying to install something and a certain command I wrote it wrong and the terminal immediately turned black and didn't allow me to see anything I am writing on.

I attached a print screen of the terminal.
It might seem as being a duplicate at first by I read every single one of the posts and didn't see anything alike or something that might help me.

This was the command I wrote on the terminal:

```
sudo st2ctl start|stop|status|restart|restart-component|reload|clean
```

but out of hurry I skipped the `s` from the `sudo` and wrote just :

```
udo st2ctl start|stop|status|restart|restart-component|reload|clean
```

and after that the terminal turned black and the rest you already know.

[image]

Comment: Does this odd behavior happen all the time ? Like when you open new terminal window ?

Comment: Yes, no matter who many restarts I did or how many terminals I open .

Comment: Did you try reinstalling terminal ? From virtual console you could do that..

Comment: I figured it out. I went through the settings and somehow discovered the colors changed, although I have no idea how . Thank you .

Comment: Great, glad to hear that :)

Comment: On a side note, you did not literally type `start|stop|status|restart|restart-component|reload|clean`, did you? The `|` notation in documentation means "or": pick one of these actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out :

I opened the terminal and went to : Edit, Profile Preferences, Color, un-checked 'Use colors from system theme', changed font color to Black and background color to white. Strange thing though, I have no idea how it got switched to 'black' background color  .